# How to eliminate null pointer exception on OpenOrCreateDatabase(****) which is called by context object of my Registration class?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-context

I am Working on simple login application in which user is first shown login screen, in login screen I have two edittext to let the user enter usrname and password. If user presses the register button then the application takes the user to registration page where the registration details in four fields named(uname,pwd, Email Add,Postal Add) entered by user should be inserted in database.

In my Registration class I have created object of my `DatabaseOperation` Class by passing the context of Registration class, then the constructor of `DatabaseOperation` is called as the constructor is called context object is copied in another object named `mcontext`. After this method named `Create_tbl` to create the table is callled.

In this method I called `OpenOrCreateDatabase()` Method with `mcontext` object as.......

```
public void Create_Tbl()
    {
    db = mcontext.openOrCreateDatabase("Register.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
    CREATE_TABLE_REGISTER = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+table_name+"(u_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,u_name TEXT,u_eadd TEXT,u_pwd TEXT,u_padd TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_REGISTER);
    }
```

My Question is : Why I am getting `NullPointerException` at `openOrCreateDatabase()`.

In addition I am getting `NullPointerException` at two other places

1. `Create_Tbl();`
2. `DatabaseOperation dos = new DatabaseOperation(Registration.this);`

Comment: how do you set mContext?

Comment: DatabaseOperation dos = new DatabaseOperation(Registration.this);

Comment: Setting context                                                                                             public DatabaseOperation(Context context)                                  {
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  mcontext = context;
  Create_Tbl();                                       }

Comment: how about `DatabaseOperation dos = new DatabaseOperation(getApplicationContext());`?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the error you are getting - at least I am sure the part of your comment ''n addition i am getting NullPointerException at two other places'' is not entirely correct. Can you please add the stacktrace of the exceptions you are getting?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev i did it there is no errors now! Thank You all for answering my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be many issues, with this problem, but most striking is mContext, please debug your code and check it is not null. and call method openOrCreateDatabase (String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory) instead of openOrCreateDatabase (String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, null).